# How to deal with access writing violation error?

Tags: c++

I created a small program to experiment with linked lists. When I ran it however, I got a "Access violation writing location" at jerry->age = 45. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Person {
    string name;
    int age;
    char gender; 
    struct Person* contact;
};

int main() {
    struct Person* jerry = (struct Person*) malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    jerry->name = "Jerry";
    jerry->age = 45;
    jerry->gender = 'M';
    jerry->contact = (struct Person*)malloc(sizeof(struct Person));;
    printf("Hi! My name is %s.\n I am %d years old.\n I am ");
    printf((jerry->gender == 'M') ? " a man.\n" : " a woman.\n", jerry->gender);
    printf("I happen to know ");
}
```

EDIT:

My new code is as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Person {
public:
    Person(const string& name, int age, char gender, const Person* contact) : _name(name), _age(age), _gender(gender), _contact(contact) {}
    
public:
    string getName() {
        return _name;
    }
    int getAge() {
        return _age;
    }
    char getGender() {
        return _gender;
    }

private:
    string _name;
    int _age;
    char _gender;
    const Person* _contact;
    /*Person* getPerson() {
        return _contact;
    }*/
};

int main() {
    Person jerry("Jerry", 45, 'M', nullptr);
    Person simon("simon", 58, 'M', nullptr);

    printf("Hi! My name is %s.\n I am %d years old.\n I am", jerry.getName(), jerry.getAge());
    printf((jerry.getGender() == 'M') ? " a man.\n" : " a woman.\n", jerry.getGender());
    printf("I happen to know ");
}
```

How would I access the pointer contact in the Person class?

Comment: Which OS and platform?

Comment: If it's c++ why are you using malloc ?

Comment: Can't reproduce with gcc.    As to problems you have not described, he first `printf()` call has undefined behaviour because it contains two format specifiers, but no corresponding arguments.

Comment: My guess is that the malloc fails because of the string inside the struct. Most probably, string uses `new` under the hood, and mixing `malloc` and `new` is bad. And it crashes on my machine/online compiler.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `malloc` to allocate your `struct`, you don't run the ctor for `std::string`.

You should create a ctor for your `struct` where you initialize correctly the string, and create the object using the ctor and not `malloc` (use `new` and `delete` when creating a pointer).

a code sample for defining the class:

```
class Person {
public:
    Person(const string& name, int age, char gender, const Person* contact) : _name(name), _age(age), _gender(gender), _contact(contact) {}

private:
    string _name;
    int _age;
    char _gender;
    const Person* _contact;
};
```

a code sample for using the class:

```
Person jerry("Jerry", 45, 'M', nullptr);
Person jerry2("Jerry2", 45, 'M', &jerry);

Person* jerry3 = new Person("Jerry3", 45, 'M', &jerry);
delete jerry3;
```

The usage of pointer for `contact` may be unsafe, and should be changed.

Comment: Creating a ctor would not help, it already has a suitable default ctor. The problem is that malloc does not call the ctor.

Comment: Correct, it's not enough, you need to create the object using the ctor and not `malloc`, added that in the answer.

Comment: Can you give an example of this code?

Comment: @Programmer - Added an example